# TSQL optimisation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have the below query which is taking 2 seconds to execute as there is a significant number of rows (1 million + each) in the two tables and was wondering if there is anything further I can do to optimise the query.

**Tables**

tblInspection.ID                bigint (Primary Key)

tblInspection.IsPassedFirstTime bit (Non clustered index)

tblInspectionFailures.ID            bigint (Primary Key)

tblInspectionFailures.InspectionID  bigint (Non clustered index)

**Query**

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblInspection.ID FROM tblInspection 
                INNER JOIN tblInspectionFailures ON tblInspection.ID = tblInspectionFailures.InspectionID 
                WHERE (tblInspection.IsPassedFirstTime = 1)
```

**Execution Plan**
[image]

I can see that I am doing clustered seeks on the indexes but its still taking some time

Comment: `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`? What are the semantics?

Comment: Its part of an IF EXISTS() query. I am checking if any records exist and then processing the results. Removing the TOP improves the performance but I don't understand why.

Comment: By way of percentage, how much of tblInspection has IsPassedFirstTime = 1? Either way, you could try creating an indexed view over this query, accepting that you'd slow down qualifying DML operations.

Comment: My guess would be that the `TOP 1` is forcing it to actually pick a record, whereas the optimiser understands the `EXISTS (SELECT *` idiom to mean "are there any records" and doesn't actually pick one. I think.

Comment: I guess the top implies a hidden sorting so that the resultset is always the same if underlying data does not change. I'd bet the complete  exists ( select * clause should provide even faster result

Comment: Index seek is as good as it gets. However, as mentioned above, the `TOP 1` is causing the extra delay in row selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing I can think of is

```
    SELECT  i.ID FROM 
    (select TOP 1 id from tblInspection 
     WHERE IsPassedFirstTime = 1) i
                    INNER JOIN tblInspectionFailures ON 
i.ID = tblInspectionFailures.InspectionID
```

Comment: Still 2 seconds and the same execution plan ;-)

Comment: OK, removing the TOP changes the execution plan to use a Merge Join and drops the execution time down to 705 milliseconds. In the original query plan the Top had 0% cost (although it must cost something to get the TOP item) I'm not sure why this is the case. Can you explain?

Comment: heck no, I can't explain.  I would just think limiting the first set to 1 row before the join would help.  joining large tables is slow, limiting them before joining uses fewer resources.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

SELECT tblInspection.ID FROM tblInspection 
            INNER JOIN tblInspectionFailures ON tblInspection.ID = tblInspectionFailures.InspectionID 
            WHERE (tblInspection.IsPassedFirstTime = 1)
```

this does basically the same thing but tells sql to stop returning rows after the 1st one

Comment: make sure to set your rowcount back to 0 to return the full queries afterwards